# how to indent tabs in command mode with command :(n, m)< with multiple tabs

Tags: vim

I am a newer to vim.In vim. In command mode by typing :(n,m)<,I can multiple indent one tab from line n to line m.

here is my question. how to indent multiple tabs in multiple lines in command mode

Comment: @user7369280 so how can I make a link to pic. and which website I can upload my pic for make a link to it?

Comment: The question editor has a  icon to upload a pic. Looks like a  mountain with the sun (right of "{}").

Comment: okay I see thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
:n,m>
```

This indents one `'shiftwidth'`. If `'shiftwidth'` is set to 0 (zero), the value of `'tabstop'` is used.

Repeat `>` for multiple indents. So

```
:n,m>>>
```

indents three levels.

See `:help :>`, `:help 'shiftwidth'` and `:help 'tabstop'`.